# How to wait for user interaction using a custom modal in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this custom modal

```
<div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="confirmModal.html">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span ng-bind="text"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn primary-btn btn2" ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
            <button class="btn primary-btn btn2" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

which I access via

```
$scope.confirm = function(text) {

    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'confirmModal.html',
        backdrop: false,
        windowClass: 'infoModal',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.text = text;

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
                return false;
            }

            $scope.delete= function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And I invoke it like that:

```
$scope.deleteFoo = function () {

     var r = $higherScope.confirm("Are you sure?");

     if(r) { /*code to delete foo*/ }
}
```

Now as you can imagine, `r` is not touched by the user's interaction, because the code doesn't wait with continuing for the user to interact with the modal.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add callback function to your `confirm` and on button clicks you need to invoke this callback, if user clicks delete trigger callback function with `true` parameter

```
$scope.confirm = function(text, callback) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'confirmModal.html',
        backdrop: false,
        windowClass: 'infoModal',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.text = text;
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                callback(false);
                $modalInstance.dismiss();

                return false;
            }

            $scope.delete= function () {
                callback(true);
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Define your callback function whit one parameter

```
$scope.deleteFooCallback = function (isConfirmed) {
     if(isConfirmed) { /*code to delete foo*/ }
}
```

Pass that callback function to `confirm` function

```
$scope.deleteFoo = function () {
     var r = $higherScope.confirm("Are you sure?", $scope.deleteFooCallback);
}
```

Comment: This practice is exactly what I searched for. Thanks.